# Form validation not working with FOR loop

Tags: php

I have 3 text fields and a hidden field. The text field accepts a date. If the date entered is later than today for any text field, it should display an error message. This only works properly if I enter a later date in the first text field. If I do it in the second or third, it continues to the redirect which obviously shouldn't happen.

```
$count = count($_POST['complete_date']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {

        if($_POST['complete_date'][$i] > date('Y-m-d')) {
            echo error_message("Date can't be in the future");
            break;

            } else {


$stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE `units` SET `complete_date` = ? WHERE `units` = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $_POST['complete_date'][$i], $_POST['units'][$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        header("location: dashboard.php");
        exit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal, if you have an error in the second or third position, you still execute your query for the first item of the array. You should do something like that :

```
$count = count($_POST['complete_date']);
$error = false;
    for($i = 0; $i < $count && ! $error; ++$i) {

    if($_POST['complete_date'][$i] > date('Y-m-d')) {
        echo error_message("Date can't be in the future");
        $error = true;

        } 
   }

  //Only process if there are no errors in all the dates
  if(! $error){
  $stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE `units` SET `complete_date` = ? WHERE `units` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $_POST['complete_date'][$i],$_POST['units'][$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    header("location: dashboard.php");
    exit();

}
```